# Animate Foundation 5 dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I've tried searching for this across the web, but I found nothing specific.

So, has anyone had an experience with Foundation 5 Top Bar? I don't see any options to make dropdown animated. It just appears. Is there some kind of a property for `data-options`. I know there are some properties like this:

```
data-options="sticky_on: medium"
```

Is there something like:

```
data-optiins="submenu_animation: fade"
```

Or something similar

Comment: This thread looks like it could be helpful: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/8318-add-easing-transition-to-top-bar-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 1):

There are no data options to add animation to the top-bar opening/closing on mobile. It will just appear and disappear. The reason is that Foundation changes the top-bar height from a specific css height value to `height: auto;` and you can't use CSS transition animations for height: auto.

You would need to completely re-work the foundation top-bar JS to create the animation yourself with javascript. Or you could set a height on `.top-bar.expanded` in CSS and then the CSS transition would work.

See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/24719200/2247931